# How do I get the AIC value out from a forecast object in R?

Tags: r, aic

I am trying to get the raw value of AIC that I can see as a result of the summary function.

```
x = forecast(ets(ts(data, start=2000, frequency=12)),h=6)
summary(x)
```

This shows me an AIC value:

```
AIC      AICc       BIC 
7.995437 27.995437  7.779078
```

When I use AIC I get this error

```
> aic <- AIC(x)
Error in UseMethod("logLik") : 
no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "forecast"
```

any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 8):

AIC is the property of the model, not of its forecast. So natural solution is to use the following code:

```
AIC(x$model)
```

You can always get more information looking at the innards of the object:

```
names(x)
```

is usually sufficiently revealing.

Answer (score -1):

```
fit<-ets(ts(data, start=2000, frequency=12))

AIC(fit)
```